# Jackson doesn't serialize hashmap

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this method:

```
private String serializeToJson(T item) {
    String json;
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    try {
        json = ow.writeValueAsString(item);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        json = "";
    }
    return json;
}
```

with this item:

[image]

and yet `json` equals:

```
{
  "saveDate" : "12:29:29 29-Mar-02015"
}
```

why is `failureDict` not serialize?

and this is the item:

```
public class FailedResponses {


    HashMap<String, Set<String>> failuresDict;
    public String saveDate;

    public FailedResponses() {

        failuresDict = new HashMap<>();
    }
```

Comment: Please show class or your item.

Comment: add public getters/setters for your fields and make the fields private. Not only is it better encapsulation but it will mean jackson can do it's magic

Comment: please add an answer so I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson will work magic on public fields or public getters and setters. I'd recommend that you make the fields of your object private for better encapsulation, and add the public getters/setters to allow jackson to de/serialize it.

Personally I like to use the jackson annotations to make it explicit what the object is being used for, and so that you have full control over the naming of the fields that jackson creates, without having to create non-idiomatic getter/setter or variable names